# Redux state becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been learning redux but I've been having problems with my state coming back undefined during the selector call.

Some code:

Selector:
`export const selectPosts = reduxState => reduxState.posts.myPost`

Action:

```
export const addPosts = ({ subId, postId, userId, content }) => ({
  type: "posts/add",
  payload: {
    userId,
    postId,
    content,
    subId
  },
});
```

Reducer:

```
const myPost = [],
      
  
  
export default function reducer(state = myPost, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "posts/add": {
        return {
            
          ...state,
          myPost: [
            ...state.posts,
            {
              userId: action.payload.userId,            
              postId: action.payload.postId,
              content: action.payload.content,
              subId: action.payload.subId,
              
            },
          ],
        };
      }
      default: {
        return state;
      }
    }
  }
```

I am calling the selector with `const posts = useSelector(selectPosts);`

I looked a lot and while there's a lot of questions that have the same issues as mine I haven't been able to make any progress.

I think it might something with the way that I'm reading the object but I haven't solved it

Thanks

Samuele-png

edit: the error I'm receiving is as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'myPost' of undefined

selectPosts
src/store/posts/selectors.js:1
> 1 | export const selectPosts = reduxState => reduxState.post.myPost
View compiled

▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.

FrontPage
src/pages/FrontPage.js:10
   7 | import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
   8 | 
   9 | export default function FrontPage() { 
> 10 | const posts = useSelector(selectPosts);
  11 | console.log(posts)
  12 |   return (
  13 |     <div>
```

Also the store

```
import userReducer from "./user/reducer";
import postReducer from "../posts/reducer";

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from "redux";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";

const devTools = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__
  ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  : (x) => x;

const enhancer = compose(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk), devTools);
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
    team: postReducer,
  }),
  enhancer
);

export default store;
```

Comment: You start your initialState as an Array state=myPosts and then returning an Object in your posts/add action - return {...state, myPost: []}

Comment: can you share how data is storing in your redux state?

Comment: Hey! do you mean store.js?
 I added it to the main post

Comment: And you are renaming postReducer to team. So while selecting you'll have to reference it by that name. const post = useSelector(state => state.team)

Comment: Hey abishek thank you so much, that fixed it for me. I cant believe I was stuck for multiple hours while the answer was in front of me. Thanks a lot!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping your posts to team in combineReducers, so you'll have to reference in useSelectors by that key.
`const posts = useSelector(state => state.team)`
Also don't change the type of your initialState that you pass to reducers
Example in your posts reducer,
You are passing an Array myPost as initialState
But later on returning an Object from reducer which can welcome more bugs.